# Direct image of a vanishing set $V_+(H(\overline{X}))$ expressed as vanishing set of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $r: \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}} \dashrightarrow 
\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}} $ be a birational map

$$ [X_0: X_1: \cdots : X_n] \mapsto [F_0(\overline{X}): \cdots
F_n(\overline{X})]$$

where $F_i(\overline{X})$ are homogeneous in
$X_0,..., X_n$ of degree $d$. Let $BL_r$ the base
locus where $r$ is not defined; that is
the vanishing set of all $F_i$. Because $r$ is birational
it is well defined on a nonempty Zariski open set
$\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}} - BL_r =
\bigcup_i D_+(F_i)$.

Let $D= V_+(H(\overline{X}))$ be a divisor defined as the vanishing set
of a homogeneous polynomial $H$ of degree $h$.

In Janos Kollar's
Resolution of Singularities on pages 36/37
is used (without giving concrete definition)
the notation of $r_*D$; the direct image of
a divisor wrt $r$.

If we start with explicite description
$ D= V_+(H(\overline{X}))$, does the direct image
$r_*D$ also have an explicite description
in vanishing polynomials?
Note, that the pullback of the divisor $r^*D$ is the vanishing set
of the polynomial $H(F_0,F_1,..., F_n)$, a homogeneous polynomial of degree $hd$. Is there a similar well known formula for $r_*D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r_*D$ is the birational transform of $D$, which means, it is the closure of $r(D-BL_r)$ in the target $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: The closure of $r(D-BL_r)$ becomes a proper closed 
subset. Can it be naturaly expressed as a vanishing 
set of certail homogeneous polynomials; that is as 
$\overline{r(D-BL_r)}= V_+(G_1, G_2,.., G_m)$ 
for $G_i$ homogeneous? And can these $G_i$ be calculated
explicitely depending on $H$ and $F_i$?

Comment: @user7391733 The closure being a closed subset it certainly is the vanishing of finitely many homogenous polynomials, (that is the Zariski topology). To get the hands on the polynomials, you will need to look at the inverse birational map $s:=r^{-1}$ and the polynomials it is given by. I don't think there is a straightforward way to write down the ideal of the birational transform. There are various notions in Kollar's Seattle notes, see birational transform of ideal, page 31, (45.1) here https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.237.344&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: an idea: if we generally have an birational map
$r: \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}} \dashrightarrow 
\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ which if given by 
polynomials 

$$  [X_0: X_1: \cdots : X_n] \mapsto [F_0(\overline{X}): \cdots
F_n(\overline{X})]$$

as above (which of course is not everywhere defined since
the $F_i$ could simultaneously become zero), 
then by birationality there should also exist an 
inverse rational map $s=r^{-1}:
\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}} \dashrightarrow 
\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: Can this $s$ also be formally written
as polynomial map

$$  [Y_0: Y_1: \cdots : Y_n] \mapsto [S_0(\overline{Y}): 
\cdots S_n(\overline{Y})]$$

albeit of course as for $r$ it is not everywhere defined? My conjecture is that maybe $r(D-BL) = s^*(D-BL)$ holds at least on open dense subsets of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: @user7391733 Yes. Birationality says that $r$ is isomorphism from a non-empty open subset of (source) $\mathbb{P}^n$ to that of target $\mathbb{P}^n$. Now there is $r^{-1}$ that is defined on $U\to \mathbb{P}^n$, it is given by a choice of $n+1$-many homogenous polynomials. Those are your $s_i$'s.

Comment: About the 'conjecture': You have to make sense of $s^*(?)$. It can't just be inverse image. You can take $s^*(D)$:=the closure of $s^{-1}(D-BL)$, which is exactly the $r_*D$ as described earlier.

Comment: Yes exactly, the motivation was to take $s^*(D):=$ closure of $s^{-1}(D-BL)$ in order to show that on an open dense set the $r_*(D)$ is the vanishing set of $V_+(H(s_0, s_1,..., s_n))$ where the $s_i$ are from birational $r^{-1}$. Does it make sense (as long as we discuss about what happens on an open dense $U$ disjoint from base loci of $r$ and $r^{-1}$?